# python: how do I randomly sample a number of samples from a population?

Tags: python, numpy

I have generated 100 samples with specific mean and variance:

```
import numpy as np
mean = 0
variance = 0.1
std_dev = np.sqrt(variance)
t = np.random.normal(mean, std_dev, 100)
print(t)
```

I want to **randomly sample 10 samples** from this population. Is there a way to extract samples randomly?

Comment: Perhaps generating a random number between 0-99 (inclusive) and using that number as an index?

Comment: Oh, that's one solution. I was wondering if there was a specific numpy module for random sampling, but thanks!

Comment: You can use [numpy.random.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the np.random.choice() function to get a numpy array of 10 random samples (second parameter is the size of the array you want)

```
import numpy as np
mean = 0
variance = 0.1
std_dev = np.sqrt(variance)
t = np.random.normal(mean, std_dev, 100)
print(t)

sample = np.random.choice(t,10)
print(sample)
```